# vue v-for object props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass an array object to a component, but am not getting anything

create.vue

```
<el-row >
      <component1 v-for="product in products" :value="product" :key="product.id"></component1>
</el-row>
```

//script section

```
data() {
    return {
       products: []  //there have (id = 1, name = first), (id = 2, name = second)
    }
}
```

component1.vue

```
<el-row>
  <div>
    {{ product.name }}
  </div>
</el-row>  

export default {
props: ['value'],
watch: {
  value: {
    hander: function (val) {
      console.log(val);

      this.product = {
        id: val.id,
        name: val.name
      } 
    },
    deep: true
  }
},
data() {
  return {
    product: {
      id: null,
      name: null
    }       
  }    
},
```

but watch not worked ( {{product.name}} its null), why? or how fixed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to watch a property that doesn't change, in your example i don't figure out  the need of using `watch` property, but you could achieve that by assigning `value` to your data property called `product` in the `mounted` life cycle hook as follows :

```
<el-row>
  <div>
    {{ product.name }}
  </div>
</el-row>  

export default {
props: ['value'],
watch: {
  value: {
    handler: function (val) {
      console.log(val);

      this.product = {
        id: val.id,
        name: val.name
      } 
    },
    deep: true
  }
},
data() {
  return {
    product: {
      id: null,
      name: null
    }       
  }    
},
mounted(){
this.product= {
        id: this.value.id,
        name: this.value.name
      } 
}
```